# Photodiode Array Wiring

Tags: arduino, wiring, light, photodiode

Sorry if this is a basic question. I would like to use photodiodes to precisely measure changes to light amplitude using an Arduino, similar to [Figure 2 here](http://outsidescience.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/diy-science-measuring-light-with-a-photodiode-ii/):

[image]

However, I would like to wire six photodiodes using a common 5V input and ground, so that wiring is minimal and the measurements occur simultaneously. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need six copies of the circuit on the breadboard. The output of each circuit connects to a different "ANALOG IN" pin on the Arduino.

There's no problem with sharing +5V and Gnd among the six circuits.

If space is at a premium, you might consider switching to the [LTC1051 or LT1053](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC1051), which are dual and quad versions, respectively, of the LTC1050.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I was worried that might be the case. It seems the OpAmp makes typical parallel wiring schemes impossible. Would phenolic stripboard be the 'best' way of installing final wirings in a project? It'll likely go in a polycarbonate box and space may be a little tight. Cheers.

Comment: @AdamErickson  Stripboard should be adequate.

Comment: Is the LTC1050 series of OpAmp the best route to go for high signal-to-noise ratio? The sensors I am looking at using are the T-5 and T-18 from Intor Inc. I was looking at the larger T-5 sensor to improve SNR, but I read an article stating that larger photodiodes can have more noise or delay due to higher capacitance. The smaller ones are cheaper, which would be nice. I would like to design a system with very low noise and high sensitivity.